# Restrict wifi router to assign ip address to LAN Users

Tags: lan

I have used two types of network in my department - LAN and WiFi network.

I have given internet access on WiFi link. The user connected to wifi, can use the internet.

When a Desktop on the same network connects using the LAN. Wifi DHCP also assign the ip address to Desktop computer.

I want that wifi router should not assign the ip address to LAN Computer. It should assign the ip address to WifI users only.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: We need more information, such as the router(s) you're using and how you are trying to separate the networks (LAN from wifi)

Comment: Consumer grade equipment mostly won't allow you to do this. You need a router with atleast two seperate vlans so you can disable dhcp on your wired lan